# while using json data shows Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token var

Tags: php, json, ajax, graph, charts

I want to get data from an url("http://localhost/icx/test/link.html") contains json data. the data contains is like

```
[{
    "call_time": "0",
    "total_inc_traffic": "1363.10",
    "total_out_traffic": "88.70"
}, {
..............
.............
}]
```

the json data "total_inc_traffic" is to be shown in the bar chart  y axix

```
    <div id="HT_IGW"></div>

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/apexcharts@latest"></script>

    <script>
            var options = {
                chart: {
                    height: 255,
                    type: 'bar',
                },
                plotOptions: {
                    bar: {
                        horizontal: false,
                        columnWidth: '55%',
                        endingShape: 'rounded'  
                    },
                },
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: false
                },
                stroke: {
                    show: true,
                    width: .5,
                    colors: ['transparent']
                },
                series: [{
                    name: 'Traffic In',
                    data: [
                        var ourRequest =new XMLHttpRequest();
                        ourRequest.open('GET','http://localhost/icx/test/link.html');
                        ourRequest.onload = function(){
                            var ourData = JSON.parse(ourRequest.responseText);

                            let result2 = ourData.map(v => Number(v.total_inc_traffic));
                            console.log(result2);
                        };
                        ourRequest.send();

                    ]
                }, {
                    name: 'Traffic Out',
                    data: [76, 85, 111, 98, 87, 115, 91, 114, 94,76, 85, 111, 98, 87, 115, 91, 114, 94,76, 85, 111,77, 98, 87]
                }, 
                ],
                xaxis: {
                    categories: ['1', '', '3', '', '5', '', '7', '', '9','','11', '', '13', '', '15', '', '17', '', '19','','21','','23',''],

                },
                yaxis: {

                },
                fill: {
                    opacity: 1

                },
                tooltip: {
                    y: {
                        formatter: function (val) {
                            return " " + val + " Calls"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            var chart = new ApexCharts(
                document.querySelector("#HT_IGW"),
                options
            );

            chart.render();


        </script>


    <script>

        var ourRequest =new XMLHttpRequest();
        ourRequest.open('GET','http://localhost/icx/test/link.html');
        ourRequest.onload = function(){
          var ourData = JSON.parse(ourRequest.responseText);

        let result = ourData.map(v => Number(v.call_time));
        console.log(result);

        let result2 = ourData.map(v => Number(v.total_inc_traffic));
        console.log(result2);

        let result3 = ourData.map(v => Number(v.total_out_traffic));
        console.log(result3);

        };
        ourRequest.send();



    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

I expected the output to be shown in the bar graph data, but it gives error data [image]

My error is this 
[image]

My expectation is

[image]

Can anyone help ??

Comment: What in the world is `data: [` doing ?

Answer (score 1):

You have an array initializer in a property definition with statements in it:

```
series: [{
    name: 'Traffic In',
    data: [ 
        var ourRequest =new XMLHttpRequest();
        ourRequest.open('GET','http://localhost/icx/test/link.html');
        ourRequest.onload = function(){
            var ourData = JSON.parse(ourRequest.responseText);

            let result2 = ourData.map(v => Number(v.total_inc_traffic));
            console.log(result2);
        };
        ourRequest.send();

    ]
```

You can't do that. With an array initializer (`[...]`) you can only have expressions in it separated with commas. The expressions are evaluated to create the values to put in the array.

It's not clear to me what you're trying to do there, but that code probably belongs after the big object initializer creating the `options` object.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot put a code block (the part starting with "var ourRequest") inside array initializer.

If you need the data obtained from ajax call to become the options.series.data property, you need to either create the options object after the ajax call is done, or create the options without that property and add to it when the ajax call is finished.

Anyway if the server that provides the json endpoint is the same as the one that is rendering the page, you should be able to render that information there right when the page is rendered, bypassing need to call any additional ajax request.
As long as you dont want to also call it to update the information without re-rendering the entire page.